# Why elastic search find case insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this index:

`"analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "meeteor_ngram" : {
              "type" : "nGram",
              "min_gram" : "2",
              "max_gram" : "15"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "meeteor" : {
              "filter" : [
                "meeteor_ngram"
              ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },`

And this document:

`{
  "_index" : "test_global_search",
  "_type" : "meeting",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "LightBulb Innovation",
    "purpose" : "The others should listen the Innovators and also improve the current process.",
    "location" : "Projector should be set up.",
    "meeting_notes" : [
      {
        "meeting_note_text" : "The immovator proposed to change the Bulb to Led."
      }
    ],
    "agenda_items" : [
      {
        "text" : "Discuss The Lightning"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

And despite the fact that I am not doing lowercase filtering nor tokenization both of these queries are returning the document:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/global_search/meeting/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "lightbulb"
        }
    }
}
'

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/global_search/meeting/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "Lightbulb"
        }
    }
}
'
```

And here is the mapping:

```
→ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/global_search/_mapping/meeting?pretty'
{
  "global_search" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "meeting" : {
        "properties" : {
          "agenda_items" : {
            "properties" : {
              "text" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "meeteor"
              }
            }
          },
          "location" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "meeteor"
          },
          "meeting_notes" : {
            "properties" : {
              "meeting_note_text" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "meeteor"
              }
            }
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "meeteor"
          },
          "purpose" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "meeteor"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your mapping?

Comment: I added @RoiHatam

Comment: @Boti Which index have the above document? is it `test_global_search` or `global_search` ? Do both indices have same mappings?

Answer (score 3):

Both `LightBulb` and `lightBulb` are returning your document because of the `custom analyzer` you created.

Check how your analyzer is tokenizing your data.

```
GET global_search/_analyze?analyzer=meeteor
{
   "text" : "LightBulb Innovation"
}
```

You will see following output:

```
{
 "tokens": [
  {
     "token": "Li",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 9,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
  },
  {
     "token": "Lig",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 9,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
  },
  {
     "token": "Ligh",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 9,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
  },
  {
     "token": "Light",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 9,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
  },
 .... other terms starting from Light

   {
     "token": "ig",      ======> tokens below this get matched when you run your query
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 9,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
  },
  {
     "token": "igh",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 9,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
  },
  {
     "token": "ight",
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 9,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
  },
  .... other tokens.
```

Now when you run `match` query  same `custom analyzer` acts and tokens the text you searched in the above manner. and Tokens like `'ig' , 'igh'` and many more get matched. That's why `match` does not seem to work.

In case of `term` query, no search analyzer acts. It searches the term as it is. If you search for `LightBulb` , it will be found in tokens. but `lightBulb` would not be found.

Hope this clarifies your question.

Study about [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) and [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

Comment: Well I need this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html

Answer (score 0):

Please add the `"index" : "not_analyzed"` to your `name` field

```
"name" : {
      "type" : "keyword",
      "index" : true
}
```

Comment: I got this:
[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [meeting]: The [string] type is removed in 5.0 and automatic upgrade failed because parameters [analyzer] are not supported for automatic upgrades. You should now use either a [text] or [keyword] field instead for field [name]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [meeting]: The [string] type is removed in 5.0 and automatic upgrade failed because parameters [analyzer] are not supported for automatic upgrades....

Comment: @Boti I'm sorry I updated the mapping to the new version. `keyword` instead of `string`, and `true` instead of `not_analyzed`

Comment: It still finds both ways 'lightbulb' and "Lightbulb". + with keyword I won't be able to search "as you type"... So I need the custom analyzer. I still don't understand why the case insensitiveness is there.

Comment: @Boti you need to delete your index `test_global_search` in order to set the new mapping. Did you do that?

Comment: I am out of ideas then

Comment: Thx anyway @RoiHatam